# Only display Firebase in-app messaging to a specific View

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

My apps(iOS and Android) is organized as follow:

- Main menu screen which has many buttons
- Each button redirects to a specific view/screen

I want to display in-app message in Main menu screen only; but currently it can show in both main screen and other screens.

How can I limit the display of in-app message to a specific screen only?

I did use firebase event to trigger the display of in-app message **after** main menu screen is opened; but if I open the main menu screen, then quickly open other screens, then in-app message is still shown.

Comment: Have you got the solution? I'm also facing the same issue. if Solved, please comment the solution.